# How to limit the number of pages that come from a same domain in search results when using Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I have indexed my crawled data into solr. When I search some words, e.g. "engineer". Within the top ten results, half of them are from one same domain. I wonder whether there is a way to limit the number of pages that come from one same domain in the search results. e.g. If a page from Yahoo already show up in ahead, is there a way that I can make other pages from Yahoo rank lower?

Comment: You can use grouping or collapse and expand to limit the number of documents returned for each group (i.e. domain). In reality you'll want to consider what you actually want to achieve - if the difference in relevance between the search results is very low for queries like that, add a small random tiebreaker instead to get more varied search results. The danger is that you'll start hiding highly relevant search hits, just because they're from a domain that already has been shown.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's really helpful!